# Trigger change event in chrome while user scrolls over number type input

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, input

The `change` event is handled differently in Chrome and in Firefox. In Firefox, when the user scrolls with mouse weel over the number type input, it triggers the `change` events, however, in Chrome it does trigger it only when the input loses focus. Open the below example both in Chrome and Firefox:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("number");
input.addEventListener("change", (evt) => console.log(`Change event: ${evt.target.value}`));
input.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => console.log(`Wheel event: ${evt.target.value}`));
```

```html
<input id="number" type="number">
```

I want to trigger the `change` event on scroll also in Chrome. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome ver 81.0.4044.138 (64-bit, Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: working for me as well

Comment: Are you sure? The change event or the wheel event? Because the change events get logged only when the input looses focus.

Comment: Wheel event triggers when scrolling, but change event only occurs when loosing focus as you said. Tried on Chrome version 87